# Splitting data from database to 3 comboboxes

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

Hello there I wanted to ask if could you split to split data from my database and populate three textboxes. I have a column in my database called DOB (date of birth) its a Varchar I wanted to populate three combo boxes with the data from that column.The code is in the navigaterecord subprocedure. This is my code :

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite
```

Public Class Form1

```
Dim inc As Integer
Dim MaxRows As Integer

Dim ConnectionString As String = "Data Source=dbRoomBookings.db"
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim mSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Customer"

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim con As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(mSQL, con)
    con.Open()
    Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(ds, "customer")
    dt = ds.Tables(0)

    MaxRows = ds.Tables("customer").Rows.Count
    con.Close()


    Dim msSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM customer;"
    dgvSearchResults.DataSource = display(msSQL, "customer")
    MaxRows = ds.Tables("customer").Rows.Count
    inc = -1

End Sub


Private Sub BtnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    If inc <> MaxRows - 1 Then
        inc = inc + 1
        navigaterecords()
    Else

        MsgBox("no more rows")
    End If

End Sub
Sub navigaterecords()

    txtCusId.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(0)
    txtFname.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(1)
    txtLname.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(2)
    cboDay.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(3)


    cboMonth.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(3) Then
    cboYear.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(3)

    txtDbo.Text = ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(3) & "/" & ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(3) & "/" & ds.Tables("customer").Rows(inc).Item(3)

End Sub

Private Sub BtnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
    If inc > 0 Then
        inc = inc - 1
        navigaterecords()
    Else

        MsgBox("no more rows")

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub BtnFirst_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFirst.Click
    If inc <> 0 Then

        inc = 0

        navigaterecords()

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub BtnLast_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLast.Click
    If inc <> MaxRows - 1 Then

        inc = MaxRows - 1

        navigaterecords()
    Else

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: First question is, why store it as a varchar?  Next, just convert it to a DateTime, then you can just use the built in Day, month & year functions to extract the values you're after

Comment: @Hursey, if I'm not mistaken, SQLite doesn't actually have a dedicated data type for dates, but there is lots of information about the about regarding working with dates. You are absolutely correct that the VB code should be working with `DateTime` values. If that was done then a single `DateTimePicker` control could be used instead of three `ComboBoxes`.

Comment: @Hursey SQLite stores dates in either of these three data types: TEXT, REAL or INTEGER as per [Data Types in SQLite Version 3](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)